# How to drilldown in highcharts using dynamic data in angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, drilldown

```
public barchart: any = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      height: 300
    },

    title: {
      text: 'barchart'

    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    accessibility: {
      announceNewData: {
          enabled: true
      }
  },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderRadius: 10,
      borderWidth: 3
  },
    xAxis: {

      title : {
        text: 'Cities',
        style: {
          color: 'black',
          font: 'bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
       }

     }, 
     categories: []
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'latitude',
        turboThreshold: 500000,
        color: '#BF0B23',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        allowpointdrilldown: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',

        data: [
          {
            name:'latitude',
            drilldown : 'latitude'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'longitude',
        turboThreshold: 500000,
        color: 'blue',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        data: [
          {
            name:'longitude',
            drilldown : 'longitude'
          }

        ]
      }
    ],

     drilldown: {
       allowPointSelect : true,
         series: [
         {


         id: 'latitude',
         data: []
        },

        {

          id: 'longitude',
          data: []
         }

        ]

    }

}

subscription: Subscription;



  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private service : ApiserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.subscription = this.service.getData().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data.cities);

      let location_id =  data.cities.map(data  =>  data.id);
      console.log(location_id);
      let location_latitude =  data.cities.map(data  =>  data.latitude);
      console.log(location_latitude);
      let location_longitude = data.cities.map(data  =>  data.longitude);
      console.log(location_longitude);
      let location_name = data.cities.map(data  =>  data.name);
      console.log(location_name);


      this.barchart['data'] = location_name;
      this.barchart.xAxis.categories = location_name;

      //this.piechart.legend.legendName = location_name;
      //console.log(this.piechart.legend.legendName);
      //this.piechart.legend.labelFormatter = location_name;


      this.barchart.series[0]['data'] = location_latitude ;
      console.log(location_latitude );
      this.barchart.series[1]['data'] = location_longitude;
      console.log(location_longitude);


      //this.barchart.drilldown = true;


       this.barchart.drilldown.series[0]['data'] =  location_latitude; 
       console.log(this.barchart.drilldown.series[0]['data']);

      this.barchart.drilldown.series[1]['data'] =  location_longitude; 
      console.log(this.barchart.drilldown.series[1]['data']);


      Highcharts.chart('bar', this.barchart);

    },
    error => {
      console.log('Something went wrong.');
    });



}



}
```

How can I add drilldown in drilldown series? I am getting data in drilldown series but drilldown is not taking place please provide solution to it.

Comment: I think you want to drill down on click of bar series. Not sure about high chart but you must have event for click on chart series which will give an object which you can use to get all relevant data for your drill down

Comment: can you provide example of that click event?

Comment: Please provide a live demo and the detailed description of how to recreate the issue. Also, have you considered using the official wrapper for Highcharts in Angular (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)? It is not reported that there are any problems with drilldown mechanism while using the wrapper.